$\exists ξ_1,ξ_2 \in (0, \frac{π}{2})$ such that $E'(ξ_1) \cdot (\frac{π}{3}-θ_1)=E'(ξ_2) \cdot (\frac{π}{3}- θ_2) $
Prove that there exist $ξ_1,ξ_2 \in (0, \frac{π}{2})$ such that  $E'(ξ_1) \cdot (\frac{π}{3}-θ_1)=E'(ξ_2) \cdot (\frac{π}{3}- θ_2)$ where $E(θ)=2(\sin(θ)\sin^2(\frac{π-θ}{2}))$ and $θ_1,θ_2 \in (0,π)$ are defined such that $Ε(θ_1)=Ε(θ_2)=\frac{2}{3}$
How I tried it:
$E'(x)=2\sin(\frac{π-x}{2}\sin(\frac{π-3x}{2}))$
$E$ has a maximum at $\frac{π}{3} $ with $E(\frac{π}{3})=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}>\frac{2}{3}$
so WLOG we can assume $θ_1 < θ_2 \implies θ_1<\frac{π}{3}<θ_2$
And this is where I get stuck. Can we continue and find a solution with this approach? is there any easier one? Any help would be appreciated!
Edit :
We can also see that $θ_2 \notin (0,\frac{π}{2})$

thanks for poionting it out I must have miss clicked

Applying twice (independently) the mean value theorem:
$$\exists\xi_1\in(\theta_1,\pi/3),\quad\frac{3\sqrt3}4-\frac23=\left(\frac\pi3-\theta_1\right)E'(\xi_1)$$
$$\exists\xi_2\in(\pi/3,\theta_2),\quad\frac{3\sqrt3}4-\frac23=\left(\frac\pi3-\theta_2\right)E'(\xi_2).$$
There remains to prove that (although $\theta_2>\frac\pi2$) $\xi_2<\frac\pi2$, i.e. $E'(\xi_2)>E'\left(\frac\pi2\right)$, i.e. $\frac{\frac{3\sqrt3}4-\frac23}{\frac\pi3-\theta_2}>-1$, i.e. $\frac\pi3+\frac{3\sqrt3}4-\frac23<\theta_2$, i.e. $E\left(\frac\pi3+\frac{3\sqrt3}4-\frac23\right)>\frac23$. You can check that $\frac\pi3+\frac{3\sqrt3}4-\frac23<1.7$ and $E(1.7)>\frac23$.
